# Different configuration based on request URL in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I need to specify different configuration options for Symfony2 (e.g. session cookie name, locale), depending on requested URL. Currently I am just matching URL with regexp in app.dev file, and loading different environments (with different config files), but this way seems to be a hack. Is there a better way to achieve it?

For example, now for url: http://example.com/de/, I am loading prod_de environment, for http://example.com/it/, I am loading prod_it.

Answer (score 1):

For Local: You Can Specify Local In Url By "{_locale}" Placeholder,
The Best Way Is Use From Event Listener: kernel.request Event

Read This [Article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-request-event)

Comment: Yep, it solves the problem with locale, but it doesn't help with session configuration. Session can start before kernel.request event in some cases.

Comment: Session doesn't start before the request - it has a priority of '128' on the kernel.request event.  All you have to do is make sure your listener has the highest priority (max 255).

Comment: Is there a reason every word of your answer is capitalized?

Comment: @JasonRoman but what if I inject session via DI, and use it in something that starts before kernel.request?

Comment: I'm not sure that would be possible?  Why would you inject via the DI, and how would you start something before kernel.request?